# How to do subversion merge cherry picking without conflicts

Tags: svn

Using svn 1.8, I cannot figure out what's the best way to do a reintegrate merge with cherrypicking (i.e. I don't want to merge all revisions back to the trunk). Everything goes smooth as long as I merge all revisions, like:

```
svn merge ^/branches/mybranch
```

Now I have one revision In my branch that shouldn't be merged back to the trunk, let's say my svn 'history' is like this:

```
rev 20: reintegrated branch => trunk
rev 21: added 'donotmergetotrunk.txt' to branch 'mybranch'
rev 22: added 'monkey.txt' to trunk
rev 23: added 'dog.txt' to branch 'mybranch'
rev 24: merged trunk => mybranch, monkey.txt added to branch
```

Now I want to reintegrate everything but revision 21 from mybranch to the trunk, but whatever I try, I keep getting the conflict

```
Tree conflict on 'monkey.txt'
    local file obstruction, incoming file add upon merge
```

I have tried stuff like:

```
svn merge -r 21:24 ^/branches/mybranch
svn merge -r 1:20 -r 21:24 ^/branches/mybranch
```

Of course the conflict can be solved manually, but in real life I get many conflicts this way and solving them gets quite tedious.

How do you perform this merge without getting conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

In your *easy case* you have to merge  `-r 23:24`

In more common case you can use smallest needed range in SRC in form `-rN:M` and exclude unwanted revisions inside this range using *reverse merge of changesets*: `-c -R`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. `svn merge -r 23:24` will only merge revision 24 (the forward merge) back to the trunk. I get the same tree conflict doing that. `svn merge -r 20:24 -c -21` also gives the tree conflict. Seems like whenever I use a range I get a tree conflict. Using svn 1.8.13 btw.

Comment: Now I notice that using the reverse merge `svn merge -r 20:24 -c -21` actually yields the proper result (after simply marking the tree conflict as resolved). dog.txt was added, and the merge info contains `/branches/mybranch:3-19,22-24` as expected. Still cannot explain the tree conflict though... I do not dear saying it out loud.... a bug maybe? :)

Answer (score 1):

When you merge branch to trunk, you should skip previous sync merges from trunk to branch.

Otherwise, subversion will try merge them back to trunk and this create conflicts:

monkey.txt was added to trunk in rev.22
rev.22 included in branch as rev. 24
then when you try merge branch to trunk, Subversion try apply rev.24 onto trunk and add monkey.txt. But it is already added! Conflict.

Also you can try to play with http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.blockchanges for block some revisions from merging into trunk. But in this case, when you block all unwanted revisions and execute on trunk

```
svn merge ^/branches/mybranch
```

Subversion can threat as reintegrate merge (which apply all differences). I am not sure how Subversion 1.8 decide if this will be sync or reintegrate merge, it is better to play with.

Comment: AFAIK, it is unwise to skip the sync merges from trunk to branch. Let's say you fixed some 'regular' conflict in the sync merge. If you skip the sync merge when doing the reintegration merge, there is no way svn knows that you have already resolved the conflict and it will give you the same conflict again. Remember that you don't encounter any strange issues if you just reintegrate everything like `svn merge ^/branches/mybranch`, not even about including the sync merge. I will read up on the link you provided (wish they released an updated 1.8 version of the red book though). Thanks.

Comment: "Remember that you don't encounter any strange issues if you just reintegrate everything like svn merge ^/branches/mybranch, not even about including the sync merge." This is because subversion 1.8 guess that this should be 'reintegrate' merge (and <1.8 require option --reintegrate). Reintegrate merge significantly different from sync merge and IMHO can't raise conflicts at all